# NodeJs with Docker on Windows - Nodemon no update

Tags: node.js, docker, nodemon

I'm trying to make nodemon work with docker so the server restarts after every change, but I can't seem to make it work.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

package.json

```
    "main": "server.ts",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "tsc -p .",
        "start": "nodemon -L src/server.ts"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "ts-node": "^8.6.2",
        "typescript": "^3.7.5"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^13.7.0",
        "eslint": "^6.8.0",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.12"
    }
```

If I run the server locally, nodemon works, but through Docker it does not (it just runs once). Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Using `nodemon` in Docker containers doesn't make sense. The reason is whenever you change some code you need to do a `docker build` to make that into an image and then run that image as container.

So, the last container actually stops and a new container starts each time you want to change a code. It is like you stopping `node` and running again.

There may be a scenario when you mount your code from host machine to the container then running `nodemon` on the mountpoint would probably be a fair choice. But for your dockerfile it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

What is the run command of your docker container? 
If you need docker container see the change you make at local, you should mount the volumes from host(local) to container like this:

```
docker run -dp 8080:8080 -v $(pwd):/usr/src/app
```

with `$(pwd)` for your current working dir(local) 
Or if you use docker-compose, mount volumes like this:

```
services:
  your_app:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes: # mount volumes here
      - ./:/usr/src/app
# rest config...
```